# Compute the maximum value by group and by time in R

Tags: r, max, aggregate

For the following Panel data (Tracking the Value for unit "ID" over "Time" :

```
ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
Value=c(1,5,4,8,2,5,9,7)
```

I would like to create a vector which is a maximum value for each "ID" and by the "Time"

Output vector "Max_Value" would be as follows:

```
Max_Value=c(1,5,5,8,2,5,9,9)
```

To clarify, here's how Max_Value is computed for ID "1".

For ID "1", the maximum value by the "Time=1" is 1, which is a maximum of {1}.

Similarly, for ID "1", the maximum value by the "Time=2" is 5, which is a maximum of {1,5}.

Again, for ID "1", the maximum value by the "Time=3" is 5, which is a maximum of {1,5,4}.

Comment: Do you need `?cummax` This would give desired output but does not take `Time` into account: `ave(Value, ID, FUN = cummax)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I cannot add comments myself, I would suggest, using @markus input:

```
library(dplyr)

ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
Time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
Value=c(1,5,4,8,2,5,9,7)


tbl <- tibble(ID = ID, Time = Time, Value = Value)
tbl %>% group_by(Time, ID) %>% mutate(result = max(Value))  ## shouldnt work

tbl %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Max_Value = cummax(Value)) ## should work
```

Comment: credits go to @markus. This answer provides the desired results, also taking **time** into account

Comment: Sorry guys, I added a wrong line of code. Edited it. Now it works!

Comment: Are you sure? I think I did it wrong again. Doenst it need to be **tbl %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Max_Value = cummax(Value))**

Comment: I found the last code with "cummax" works well. I haven't tried the line with "max" yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                 Value=c(1,5,4,8,2,5,9,7))

max_v <- function(x) max(dt[ID==x$ID & Time <= x$Time, Value])

sapply(split(dt,1:nrow(dt)),max_v)
```

You can also try:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Time=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                 Value=c(1,5,4,8,2,5,9,7))

dt <- dt[order(Time)]

dt[,Max_Value := cummax(Value), by=ID]

dt[order(ID)]
#    ID Time Value Max_Value
# 1:  1    1     1         1
# 2:  1    2     5         5
# 3:  1    3     4         5
# 4:  1    4     8         8
# 5:  2    1     2         2
# 6:  2    2     5         5
# 7:  2    3     9         9
# 8:  2    4     7         9
```

Comment: Why not `dt[, new := cummax(Value), by=ID]`?